# Drag and drop images and reverting images to a specific area using jquery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, shopping-cart

I am new to jquery.Presently i am developing a website where few images must be dragged into one shopping cart and few in other.

For example tshirts must be dropped in first shopping cart and shoes in the second shopping cart
but the reverse should not happen(tshirts should not drop in the second shopping cart and shoes should not drop in the first shopping cart).

I developed a part of code where everything is dropping into two shopping carts
but only one shopping cart is displaying the name and price.

I want both the shopping cart display the name and price but the first shopping cart should accept only shirts and the other only shoes and display the name and price.

plz try to solve my problem.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Building a drag-drop shopping cart - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;">
<h2 style="width: 205px">Shopping Cart</h2>
<div class="easyui-panel" fit="true" border="false" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="cart1" style="left: 5px; top: 0px; height: 309px; bottom: 0px; width: 255px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cartcontent0" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px">Drop here to add to cart</div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="cart" style="left: -9px; top: -62px; height: 309px; bottom: 62px; width: 269px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px">Drop here to add to cart</div>
    </div>
    <div class="products" style="width: 203px; height: 277px;">
        <ul>
         <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="107" width="85"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Feeling</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt3.gif" height="86" width="81"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Elephant</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt4.gif" height="84" width="76"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Stamps</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



<div class="productss" style="width: 203px; height: 277px;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="itemm">
                    <img src="images/shoes1.gif" height="93" width="108"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>puma</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="width: 122px; height: 126px">
                <a href="#" class="itemm">
                    <img src="images/shoes2.gif" height="84" width="102"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>puma</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
</div>

    <style type="text/css">
        .products{
            overflow:auto;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .products ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .products li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .productss{
            overflow:auto;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .productss ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .productss li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .item{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }

        .itemm{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .itemm img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .itemm p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }

        .cart{
            float:right;
            position:relative;
            width:260px;
            height:100%;
            background:#ccc;
            padding:0px 10px;
        }
        .ctitle{
            text-align:center;
            color:#555;
            font-size:18px;
            padding:10px;
        }
    .cart1 {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        width: 260px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
        padding: 0px 10px;
            }
    .auto-style1 {
        margin-left: 10;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#cartcontent').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true,
                showFooter:true
            });
            $('#cartcontent0').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true,
                showFooter:true
            });

            $('.item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });

            $('.itemm').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });

                $('.cart').droppable({
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                }
            });

            $('.cart1').droppable({
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                }
            });




        });

        function addProduct(name,price){
            var dg = $('#cartcontent');
            var data = dg.datagrid('getData');
            function add(){
                for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name){
                        row.quantity += 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name:name,
                    quantity:1,
                    price:price
                });
            }
            add();
            dg.datagrid('loadData', data);
            var cost = 0;
            var rows = dg.datagrid('getRows');
            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                cost += rows[i].price*rows[i].quantity;
            }
            dg.datagrid('reloadFooter', [{name:'Total',price:cost}]);
        }

        function addProduct(name,price){
            var dg = $('#cartcontent0');
            var data = dg.datagrid('getData');
            function add(){
                for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name){
                        row.quantity += 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name:name,
                    quantity:1,
                    price:price
                });
            }
            add();
            dg.datagrid('loadData', data);
            var cost = 0;
            var rows = dg.datagrid('getRows');
            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                cost += rows[i].price*rows[i].quantity;
            }
            dg.datagrid('reloadFooter', [{name:'Total',price:cost}]);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `function addProduct(name,price){` two times which is not correct, you can pass third item as id. And for accepting particular `draggable` class in `droppable` use accept argument of `droppable` like `accept: '.item'`

Updated code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Building a drag-drop shopping cart - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;">
<h2 style="width: 205px">Shopping Cart</h2>
<div class="easyui-panel" fit="true" border="false" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="cart1" style="left: 5px; top: 0px; height: 309px; bottom: 0px; width: 255px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cartcontent0" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px">Drop here to add to cart</div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="cart" style="left: -9px; top: -62px; height: 309px; bottom: 62px; width: 269px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px">Drop here to add to cart</div>
    </div>
    <div class="products" style="width: 203px; height: 277px;">
        <ul>
         <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="107" width="85"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Feeling</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt3.gif" height="86" width="81"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Elephant</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt4.gif" height="84" width="76"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Stamps</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



<div class="productss" style="width: 203px; height: 277px;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="itemm">
                    <img src="images/shoes1.gif" height="93" width="108"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>puma</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="width: 122px; height: 126px">
                <a href="#" class="itemm">
                    <img src="images/shoes2.gif" height="84" width="102"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>puma</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
</div>

    <style type="text/css">
        .products{
            overflow:auto;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .products ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .products li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .productss{
            overflow:auto;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .productss ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .productss li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .item{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }

        .itemm{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .itemm img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .itemm p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }

        .cart{
            float:right;
            position:relative;
            width:260px;
            height:100%;
            background:#ccc;
            padding:0px 10px;
        }
        .ctitle{
            text-align:center;
            color:#555;
            font-size:18px;
            padding:10px;
        }
    .cart1 {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        width: 260px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
        padding: 0px 10px;
            }
    .auto-style1 {
        margin-left: 10;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#cartcontent').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true,
                showFooter:true
            });
            $('#cartcontent0').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true,
                showFooter:true
            });

            $('.item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });

            $('.itemm').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });

                $('.cart').droppable({
                accept: '.item',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]), '#cartcontent');
                }
            });

            $('.cart1').droppable({
                accept: '.itemm',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]), '#cartcontent0');
                }
            });




        });

        function addProduct(name, price, dgId){
            var dg = $(dgId);
            var data = dg.datagrid('getData');
            function add(){
                for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name){
                        row.quantity += 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name:name,
                    quantity:1,
                    price:price
                });
            }
            add();
            dg.datagrid('loadData', data);
            var cost = 0;
            var rows = dg.datagrid('getRows');
            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                cost += rows[i].price*rows[i].quantity;
            }
            dg.datagrid('reloadFooter', [{name:'Total',price:cost}]);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```